# Why can't white holes exist?

Tags: black-holes, multiverse, white-holes

1. Why can't white holes exist?
2. Also considering that there are infinite universes with infinite possibilities can there be a universe where white holes can exist and black holes cant, or maybe they can co-exist in the same universe?

Comment: Who said white holes can't exist?

Comment: White holes are a sort of extreme mathematical extension of black holes.  They are not known to exist and while we've detected black holes, we have not detected white holes.  I think there is a general skepticism of their actual existence as against their being just a mathematical step-too-far with the theory.    We have no reason to think there are or are not infinite universes.  We're certain there is at least one universe, but we've no evidence for more than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that they *can't* exist, it's rather they're *extremely unlikely* to exist, and furthermore if they did, they would be gone shortly after they came into existence.

The term "extremely unlikely" above is meant in the same sense it is meant in the case of a spontaneous fluctuation leading to a decrease in entropy. The evolution of a white hole forward in time is the time-reversal of the evolution of a black hole forward in time - equivalently, it is as though a black hole were evolving *backward* in time: it corresponds to a process of *decreasing* entropy (whereas that of a black hole is *increasing* entropy), which is extremely unlikely - but not *impossible* - to occur spontaneously. (That is the correct and airtight statement of the second law of thermodynamics - a statistical one discussing the *likelihood* of entropy to go in either direction.) It is exactly the same situation as, say, imagining by sheer chance that a broken coffee mug laying on the ground will experience just such a conspiracy of inverted forces arising from the ground and air to whinny it back up and cause it to spontaneously reassemble itself into an intact one sitting on the table again. It is not impossible because the laws of physics are reversible - if we invert the sign on all parameters that describe the forward motion of everything relevant, the resulting motion will be exactly equivalent to "playing the movie backwards". But it is exceedingly *unlikely* for that to happen, as our common sense would seem to indicate to us. It's just that a white hole is a little less "obvious" since we tend to imagine something that superficially seems plausible (e.g. a "white mouth" bursting forth with matter and energy spewing out like a firehose), but in actuality, it's no different. The formation and evolution of a white hole would be essentially the "movie" of the formation and evolution of a black hole from its birth as an imploding star to its death as a burst of Hawking radiation, but played backwards in reverse, and acted out with ever-soooo-exquisitely; and delicately, and lovingly, arranged physical constituents in such a terribly fortuitous act of happenstance, that it would be a miracle by any definition, exactly as with our coffee cup scenario.

The only way it could *not* be *possible* is if black holes are truly irreversible, that is, information is truly lost when they are formed and when matter falls in. But this is not believed to be the case, as it seems to go against fundamental principles of physics including quantum mechanics.

That said, it is easier for a small system to fluctuate downward in entropy than a large one. Thus it might be realistically possible for very small white holes to form - but since we don't know the lower limiting mass for a black hole, this could be unfeasible too (namely the end of the white hole must be *at least* this mass since it is equivalent to the *beginning* of the black hole.). That lower limiting mass almost surely cannot be any larger than the Planck mass, but there are speculative ideas (like some types of string theory) that say black holes can have even lower masses. Failing such theories as being true (none of them have been seen to be true in any experiment done so far), the chance for even a Planck-mass fluctuation is extremely small: the Planck mass is about the mass of a flea, and how often have you seen a flea spontaneously freeze itself, in warm weather, into an Anarctic-cold popsicle? Exactly. The chance to form a white hole would be even worse.

Finally, one might contest that despite all this, the Hawking radiation itself from a usual black hole is at least in some ways *reminiscent* of a white hole: it does, after all, emit energy outward. But it is not in others: in particular a white hole's event horizon cannot be crossed through from outside to inside, and this is most certainly not true of a black hole. Nonetheless, it's the closest there is that one can be pretty sure actually exists out there.

--

Now as for your other question, parallel universes: The answer to this would depend on how exhaustive the multiverse is, something which, along with the notion of a multiverse itself, is totally speculative. If it is exhaustive enough though, then yes, every possibility however unlikely will be realized, so there will be universes with white holes, and astronomers observing them, mouths agape with the greatest awe for they're witnessing a literal miracle. Likewise there will also be universes where a human actually witnessed a broken mug spontaneously leap back up off the floor and reassemble itself intact and flawless on the table, and break down in soft tears that their beloved mug had returned to them ... (aww ...) And there will be universes out there were a wind-swept desert had dunes in it which spelled out the words "Here be DRAGONS", and another where someone's bed started talking to them in the middle of the night (not a hallucination, but spontaneous vibrations that were legible speech emanating literally from the bed itself physically), telling them to do things with their hair the next day, and to which they would willingly oblige, and then dutifully carry it out and turn their hair into a wild spiky and multicolor-dyed mess with ice cream cones stuck in it and a single dread hanging off once site and cut-out oranges over their eyes with slits in front so they could see from them, with the orange juice having been squeezed into the hair so as to make it stink.

EDIT: I notice something that should be mentioned in the above and that's that when it comes to reversing all the relevant parameters, simply reversing velocities, etc. is not enough to get the time reversal. Because of the way the weak force works, you also have to exchange particles with their antiparticles to get the "true" time reversal. But given that a black hole can form as much from antimatter as matter, this would *seem* not to be a problem, even if we imagine it evolving to spit forth matter (that would correspond to reversal of a black hole that had formed from antimatter. The reverse of a black hole formed from matter would discharge antimatter, not matter.).

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot. I am still a little confused about white holes being able to exist, you explained it as "playing the movie backward", but in the case of a white hole wouldn't time itself be rewinding? Due to this, I assumed it was impossible for white holes to exist as time as we know it cannot go in the other direction.

Comment: @gulu25 : It's not about time going backwards, it's about a system that is physically equivalent to time going backwards. Such can be obtained by reversing the sign of all relevant parameters exactly, because the relevant dynamical laws can produce the reverse-time evolution as much as they can the forward-time evolution: all you need to do is reverse the appropriate parameters for all the constituents of the system and the laws will create, going forwards in time, the same result as if the original system was going backwards in time. It's just that this exactly-reversed configuration (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) is exquisitely unlikely to occur naturally.

Comment: The simplest example is Newton's laws. Take for example a free particle, moving under a steady acceleration. Its motion is given by $x(t) = \frac{1}{2}at^2 + v_0 t + x_0$. If you find the time-reversed path $x_R(t) = x(-t)$, you get $x_R(t) = \frac{1}{2}at^2 - v_0 t +x_0$, which is the same evolution as for a particle moving forward in time but with the opposite velocity.

Comment: Likewise, you can consider a gas of many particles, which will spontaneously entropize. But since each particle is governed by very similar rules (the only forces are the collisions), you can reverse the particle velocities and you will get a gas that de-entropizes. But make it even a bit off (e.g. maybe another particle flies in from outside), and that might not happen, thus, extremely unlikely (namely, the disturbance will propagate and spoil the delicate conspiracy) to have such a state in reality. I suspect a white hole could likely be similarly "spoiled", making it even less likely.